# Help with vectorial analysis problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Let $\psi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable functions. Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $Y=\psi(X)$ and $g=f \circ \psi$. Show that $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal to $\nabla g(X)$ if and only if $\psi'(X)(Z)$ is orthogonal to $\nabla f(Y)$.

Well, I've tried many things (like the geometric meaning of the gradient operator and direct manipulation using inner product properties) but nothing worked and I did not see any other valid aproach.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, what is the definition of $g$?  You wrote $g = f \circ g$, which, uh...

Comment: Edited, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by the chain rule
$$
\nabla g(X)=\nabla f(Y)\psi'(X)
$$
Where $\psi'(X)$ is the $n\times n$ matrix $\left(\frac{\partial\psi_i}{\partial x_j}(X)\right)$, $\psi=(\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_n)$.

Given $Z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we can interpret the dot product $\nabla g(X)\cdot Z$ as the product of the $1\times n$ matrix $\nabla g(X)$ and the $n\times 1$ which is the transpose of  $Z$ (viewed as a $1\times n$ matrix).
So
$$
\nabla g(X)Z=(\nabla f(Y)\psi'(X))Z=\nabla f(Y)(\psi'(X)Z)
$$
This implies that $\nabla g(X)Z=0$ if and only if $\nabla f(Y)(\psi'(X)Z)=0$ and since $\psi'(X)Z\in \mathbb{R}^n$,   tour claim follows.